# Python, logging: wrong pathname when extending Logger

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to create a custom logger this way:

File: logger.py

```
import logging

class Logger(logging.getLoggerClass()):
    def warning(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Logger, self).warning(msg, *args, **kwargs)

logging.setLoggerClass(Logger)
log = logging.getLogger('test')
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(pathname)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(handler)
```

File: test.py

```
from logger import log

log.warning('')
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py
/home/dario/Desktop/logging_test/logger.py
```

The expected output would be:

```
/home/dario/Desktop/logging_test/test.py
```

What's even weirder, if I comment the `setLoggerClass` line I do get `test.py`, but without the full path.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Tested with Python 2.7.4 and 3.3.1 on Arch Linux x86_64.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to subclass the logger class?

Comment: My goal is formatting the log messages in different ways depending on their level; everything works fine except for this thing, but I'm still testing it 'cause I'm pretty sure at some point in the development I was indeed getting the right path

Comment: Probably simpler to use [Handlers](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#handlers).

Comment: Is there a way to make a handler handle only one specific log level (e.g. INFO) ignoring all the others?

Comment: Yep, using filters, thanks! I'll look into that, but first I want to understand this behaviour fully :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Python Documentation - Logging - LogRecord attributes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes):

> **%(pathname)s** - Full pathname of the source file where the logging call was issued (if available).

I.e. where a `logging` object, (or any subclass, like `Logger`) was initialized.
In this case `logging` and your instance of it, `log`, is both defined and initialized in the same file `test.py`.

Maybe it's a bit clearer if I split up the files:

**logger.py:** (the class)

```
import logging                                           

# This is the path `logging` gets                        
class Logger(logging.getLoggerClass()):                  
    def warning(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):             
        super(Logger, self).warning(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

**log.py:** (a `log` module which has a `log` object of the type `Logger`)

```
import logging
from logger import Logger

logging.setLoggerClass(Logger)
log = logging.getLogger('test')
handler = logging.StreamHandler()

# Not this file's path, but where class Logger
# creates a logging object with super()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(pathname)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(handler)
```

**test.py:** (main)

```
from log import log

log.warning('')
```

Comment: More correctly, it's where the base logger class's method was called from, not where it was defined, although they happen to be the same file in this example.

Comment: Then why if I don't extend Logger, pathname doesn't return `/usr/lib/.../logging/__init__.py` (where the original `Logger` class is defined) but `test.py`?

Comment: @kynikos Again, it's where the `warning()` method was called from, not where it was defined.

Comment: So it's because of the `super` call, sorry I didn't get it. Then I guess there's _no way_ to get the correct pathname when extending the Logger class this way... Thank you again

Comment: @kynikos You could use `%(name)` instead. Take a look at [logging configuration](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) to make it easier to use.

Comment: Thanks timss, however I need the path of the file where the call was made, not the logger name, which is what `%(name)` displays; anyway solving this problem with filters, as mentioned in the comments to the question, is a better solution

Comment: @kynikos actually, you can get the correct pathname, but it's much more complicated than using handlers.

Comment: Yeah I've had a look at the source of the logging module to see how it gets pathname, I should probably override more classes/methods, really not worth it ^^'