# Custom log level accurate filename

Tags: python, logging, path, formatting

#### TLDR

How can I get a *custom* logging level to accurately find out the pathname?

#### Problem description

When I try and add my own custom logging levels (e.g. for very verbose program tracing) I want to print the pathname. For most of the standard loggers, it is able to get this correctly, but for my own custom loggers, these all ultimately call `logging.log(levelNum, message, *args, **kwargs)` with `levelNum` as my custom level number. This means that only this line is ever printed, not the desired line.

A similar issue was raised here: [Python, logging: wrong pathname when extending Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16122712/5134817) and in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122712/python-logging-wrong-pathname-when-extending-logger#comment23029914_16122821) by "[Aya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172176/aya)" they say:

> actually, you can get the correct pathname, but it's much more complicated [...]

I am currently using [the formatter approach outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859558/5134817), and the [adding of the log levels outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35804945/5134817).

***Is there a way to get the desired behaviour?***

#### Some example code

The output from the below is:

```
/Users/oliver/ClionProjects/testing/venv/bin/python3 /Users/oliver/ClionProjects/testing/misc/misc.py 
writing some logs...
DEBUG: (/Users/oliver/ClionProjects/testing/misc/misc.py:90) something debug message
TRACE: (/Users/oliver/ClionProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/haggis/logs.py:211) something trace message
[2023-08-18 19:10:17,539]: WARNING: (/Users/oliver/ClionProjects/testing/misc/misc.py:92) something warning message

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Notably, the trace line is showing the wrong file path...

##### The code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Some wrapping around the default logging module.
"""

import logging
import sys
from haggis.logs import add_logging_level
from termcolor import colored


class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """A nice formatter for logging messages."""
    line_formatting = f" {colored('(%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d)', 'light_grey')}"
    timestamp_formatting = f"{colored('[%(asctime)s]: ', 'green')}"
    trace_format = f"{colored('TRACE', 'cyan')}:{line_formatting} %(msg)s"
    debug_format = f"{colored('DEBUG', 'magenta')}:{line_formatting} %(msg)s"
    info_format = f"{colored('INFO', 'blue')}:{line_formatting} %(msg)s"
    print_format = f"%(msg)s"
    warning_format = f"{timestamp_formatting}{colored('WARNING', 'yellow')}:{line_formatting} %(msg)s"
    error_format = f"{timestamp_formatting}{colored('ERROR', 'red')}:{line_formatting} %(msg)s"
    critical_format = f"{timestamp_formatting}{colored('CRITICAL', 'red', attrs=['reverse', 'blink', 'bold'])}: {line_formatting} %(msg)s"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(fmt=f"UNKNOWN: %(msg)s", datefmt=None, style='%')

    def format(self, record):

        # Save the original format configured by the user
        # when the logger formatter was instantiated
        format_orig = self._style._fmt

        # Replace the original format with one customized by logging level
        if record.levelno == logging.TRACE:
            self._style._fmt = MyFormatter.trace_format
        elif record.levelno == logging.DEBUG:
            self._style._fmt = MyFormatter.debug_format
        elif record.levelno == logging.INFO:
            self._style._fmt = MyFormatter.info_format
        elif record.levelno == logging.PRINT:
            self._style._fmt = MyFormatter.print_format
        elif record.levelno == logging.WARNING:
            self._style._fmt = MyFormatter.warning_format
        elif record.levelno == logging.ERROR:
            self._style._fmt = MyFormatter.error_format
        elif record.levelno == logging.CRITICAL:
            self._style._fmt = MyFormatter.critical_format
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError(f"We don't know how to format logging levels: {record.levelno}")

        # Call the original formatter class to do the grunt work
        result = logging.Formatter.format(self, record)

        # Restore the original format configured by the user
        self._style._fmt = format_orig

        return result


class StdOutFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, rec):
        return rec.levelno <= logging.PRINT


class StdErrFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, rec):
        stdout_filter = StdOutFilter()
        return not stdout_filter.filter(rec)


def setup_console_output():
    fmt = MyFormatter()
    stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    stdout_handler.setFormatter(fmt)
    stdout_handler.addFilter(StdOutFilter())
    logging.root.addHandler(stdout_handler)
    stderr_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
    stderr_handler.setFormatter(fmt)
    stderr_handler.addFilter(StdErrFilter())
    logging.root.addHandler(stderr_handler)


add_logging_level('TRACE', logging.DEBUG - 5)
add_logging_level('PRINT', logging.WARNING - 5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.root.setLevel(logging.TRACE)
    setup_console_output()
    print("writing some logs...")
    logging.debug("something debug message")
    logging.trace("something trace message")
    logging.warning("something warning message")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Increase the `stacklevel`

So after learning more about stack levels when reading about warnings, it seems the logging module also has this functionality.

Inside of the `logToRoot` function (either in the `haggis` module or the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35804945/5134817)) there is a call to:

```py
logging.log(levelNum, message, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here tell this to refer to the calling stack, by increasing the stack level from its default value of `1` up to `2`, via:

```py
logging.log(levelNum, message, *args, **kwargs, stacklevel=2)
```

After doing this the output matches what is expected:
[image]
produces:

```
DEBUG: (/Users/oliver/ClionProjects/testing/misc/misc2.py:141) something debug message
TRACE: (/Users/oliver/ClionProjects/testing/misc/misc2.py:142) something trace message
[2023-08-23 11:57:33,845]: WARNING: (/Users/oliver/ClionProjects/testing/misc/misc2.py:143) something warning message
```